# Is there any software that allows me to read text binary files in windows?

Tags: linux, windows, unix, binary

I have some binary files that have chapters of a book (the files have no extension) is there any software that allows me to access there content? In other words to convert binary to English?

I tried several solutions...

Thank you

Comment: are you referring to .bin files?

Comment: no they are not .bin. I have tried all text editors I can remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for a very "basic" try,

first of all, try to :

```
file  the_file
```

to see if it is a known format. Then rename the file accordingly and open it using the proper program.

If this fails, you could use a very low level approach:

```
string the_file  >   the_strings_of_the_file
```

to create a new file (the_strings_of_the_file) containing "strings" from the_file.

It is probably cluttered with meaningless things, and the (few?) sentences can probably be in whatever order...

You may try to narrow down the potentially good ones with some filters:

```
string the_file | grep  some_regexp  > the_strings_of_the_file.filtered_in
string the_file | grep  -v some_regexp  > the_strings_of_the_file.filtered_out
```

and adjust some_regexp until the "filtered_out" do not contain anything of value...

(I could help with the regexp if you provide us some of the output of "strings", both meaningful ones and some non-meaningfull ones)

(and if you precise what kind of langage is used: ascii? accentuated letters? etc)

Another approach: delete "non usefull" letters:

```
tr -cd ' -~\n\t' the_file > the_file_without_weird_letters
# note that if your file contain accentuated letters, you'll need to change the range.
# The range above is good for "everything printable in regular ascii"
```

Comment: @user1419224: For curiousity sake, I'd be interrested if you can tell me which of the steps I gave you helped you ^^